# Child class instantiation, automatically set the discriminator property for me (Code First)

Tags: c#, inheritance, code-first, instantiation, discriminator

I have a parent abstract class:

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TransactionDescr { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }        
    public int TransactionType { get; protected set; }
}
```

And some real child classes that I want to set the `TransactionType` property when it instantiated.

In my database, I have a `TransactionType` column  which I use as the discriminator.

This is my idea:

```
public class TransactAdd : Transaction
{
    public TransactAdd()
    {
        TransactionType = 1;
    }
}
public class TransactDeduct : Transaction
{
    public TransactDeduct()
    {
        TransactionType = 2;
    }
}
public class TransactTransfer : Transaction
{
    public TransactTransfer()
    {
        TransactionType = 3;
    }
}
```

Is it a good idea to set the `TransactionType` in class constructor?? am I right? or is there a better way?

By the way, finally, I save the **parent class `Transaction`** in the database using Dapper.

I add the solution, thanks to @flobjective

**UPDATE(Solution)**

```
public abstract class Transaction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string TransactionDescr { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }        
    public abstract int TransactionType { get; }
}

public class TransactAdd : Transact
{
    public override int TransactType
    {
        get
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
public class TransactDeduct : Transact
{
    public override int TransactType
    {
        get
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
public class TransactTransfer : Transact
{
    public override int TransactType
    {
        get
        {
            return 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does a type of `1` mean? I would use an enum (with descriptive names) instead of magic numbers.

Comment: Actually I've used `Enum` in final edit. I was too lazy to put the complete code here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One weakness of your solution is that you have to remember to set the transaction type. In case somebody else adds a new Transaction class he may forget and this will lead to a wrong `TransactionType` value of `1`.

Other than that `intTransactionType` has protected setter which means somebody could later change the type which could lead to problems.

You could create an abstract method `(Get)TransactionType` that forces each concrete implementation to return an int. However that still does not ensure that you use unique integers for all types.

Comment: Thank you. As I understand, I need to get rid of the setter method and make the property abstract in the parent.

Comment: So it is like: `public abstract int TransactionType { get; }` in the parent and : `public override int TransactionType { get { return 1; } }` in the child. yes?

Comment: Yes, that what I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might be a solution for me but read-only data isn't written to the database and I need this data to be part of a composite key. Now if there was a way to use the discriminator as part of my composite key strategy then it would be perfect

```
Public Overrides ReadOnly Property AddressType As AddressType
    Get
        Return AddressType.Consignee
    End Get
End Property
```